# Is conditional lookup or stage addition possible on Mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a sample schema like this (since it's not real, please ignore normalization issues):

```
{
  "cars": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "item": "SUV",
      "brand_type": "private",
      "brand_description_id": 1,
      "price": 12,
      "quantity": 2
    },
    
  ],
  "brand_description": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "description": "spaceship car"
    }
  ],
  "private_brand_description": [
    {
      "_id": 1,
      "description": "turtle car"
    }
  ]
}
```

I basically should retrieve the `description` of the brand from the collection `private_brand_description` if `car`'s **brand_type** is `private` and if `car`'s **brand_type** is `public`, I should retrieve the `description` from `brand_description` collection.

I can apply it to filter once (i.e. `private` in the example below), but I can't apply it to another type later on aggregation.

I tried to replicate the problem I am facing on Mongodb to play with: https://mongoplayground.net/p/o69_HP-WgDW

I had another solution with `$facet`, but it has its downsides, it runs both aggregations everytime then filters.

Imagine I use `$mergeObjects` to merge private and public fields:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/XDGQbOLmWqO

Please note that I can't change database schema.

What I would like it better is if I can check the brand_type earlier than `$lookup` stage, I can later lookup for related collection so that database won't perform the lookups unnecessarily.

Comment: a double lookup? https://mongoplayground.net/p/Xpcu3AqHKm-

Comment: There is no conditional stage option in MongoDB, double lookups like the above are the way to go